# Why is my website slow on the domain and fast on localhost?

Tags: windows, performance, apache, ip, wamp

I'm using WAMP on Windows 8 to serve a website, and the website is very fast on localhost, but very slow on my public domain address. 
Why is that? 
My internet speed should be fine, its around 80 Mbps down and 10 Mbps up.
My IP hasn't changed for months, so I'm not using any dynamic DNS service.
I have i7 3.5ghz with 8gb ram, which shouldn't cause the problem.
I am using owncloud, which loads up painfully slow on the internet, but lightning fast on localhost.

Comment: A local server should always be faster. If you think there is something else at play, do some benchmarking.

Comment: Remember you are using a Desktop OS, W8 like other desktop OS's has a low limit for the number of external connections i.e. 20 on W8 I believe. If you are being accessed by many clients at the same time, this will slow everything down. In fact it will only take a few clients to consume 20 connections as each client will use more than one connection.

Comment: The site is a private password protected cloud so only I can access it

Answer (score 0):

Because accessing by domain should pass through DNS Server to translate domain name to IP address. So it costs more time than localhost.